# How can I invoke a drush hook on a remote alias?

Tags: drush

I have a local dev environment and a test server environment.  Both are running the exact same code.

In a custom module, I added a drush hook to extend the *sql_sanitize* command in order to ensure all private user data is removed from the development database.

From a directory within my local environment, I can invoke drush like this:

> drush sql-sanitize

And my custom drush hook is run properly.

However, when I invoke drush from the same location but targeting my remote server environment (Pantheon, if it matters, and I [checked their documentation](http://helpdesk.getpantheon.com/customer/portal/articles/411388-drush-command-line-utility), but didn't see any relevant notes):

> drush @mytestserver sql-sanitize

*sql-sanitize* resolves, but the custom drush hook is not called, even though the module containing the hook is enabled locally and on the test server.

I tried invoking the command from a directory outside my local dev environment, but again *sql-sanitize* resolved without the custom drush hook being called.

How can I execute the drush hook in a remote environment from my local machine?

I have tried both Drush 5.9 and 6.4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually "solved" this by moving the SQL into `myfile.sql` and running it like this:

`drush @myalias sql-connect` < myfile.sql

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, we had a similar problem with drush < 6.4, drush was not passing the alias to the remote server if `root` and `uri` where not specified.

One way to solve it is to define `$conf['root']` and `$conf['uri']` in your local alias, the other is to use drush 7.